# overlappings of more than one analytic complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

imagine $f_1$ is analytic over $S_1$.

$f_2$ is analytic over $S_2$.

$f_3$ is analytic over $S_3$.

if in $S_1 ‎\cap_{}^{} S_2$  , $$f_1=f_2$$
and in if in $S_2 ‎\cap_{}^{} S_3$  , $$f_2=f_3$$

is it true that in if in $S_1 ‎\cap_{}^{} S_3$  , $$f_1=f_3$$

for checking this I thought there could be two states in the first state where $S_1 ‎\cap_{}^{} S_2 \cap_{}^{} S_3 \neq \emptyset$ then we can use the equalities mentioned to conclude that all three functions are equal in $S_1 ‎\cap_{}^{} S_2 \cap_{}^{} S_3$. then with using the theoream "The behavior of a function that is analytic in a region
$S ⊂ C$ is completely determined by its behavior in a (small) neighborhood
of an arbitrary point in that region" we can understand that $f_1=f_3$ is true in $S1 ‎\cap_{}^{} S_3$
.
but I don't know what to do if $S_1 ‎\cap_{}^{} S_2 \cap_{}^{} S_3 = \emptyset$

Comment: You certainly need some connectedness condition for your domains. If $A,B,C$ are disjoint open sets and $S_1=A\cup B,S_2=B\cup C,S_3=C\cup A$, then your conjecture doesn't hold.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos thanks. the sets are connected subsets of complex plain. if they are connected but still $S_1 ‎\cap_{}^{} S_2 \cap_{}^{} S_3 = \emptyset $ is the conjecture true? if not can u give a counterexample for the functions.

Comment: Then take $S_1=S_3=:S$ and $S_2$ disjoint of both, and let $f_1\neq f_3$ and $f_2$ some arbitrary analytic function. Now vacuously $f_1=f_2$ on $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$ and $f_2=f_3$ on $S_2\cap S_3=\emptyset$, but $f_1\neq f_3$ on $S_1\cap S_3=S$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos thanks again for your help. i actually meant if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are connected and $S_2$ and $S_3$ are connected and also $S_1$ and $S_3$ are connected. but $S_1 \cap_{}^{} S_2 \cap_{}^{} S_3 = \emptyset $.

Comment: Do you mean that the sets are pairwise overlapping? Because being connected has a precise meaning, which applies to single sets, not pairs of sets: An open set is connected if it is not the union of two disjoint, non-empty open sets.
But we still get a counterexample: Consider a kind of ring around 0, and cut the ring into three pairwise overlapping segments. You can now define analytic branches of the natural logarithm on each of them such that they agree on the intersection of the 1st and 2nd segment, as well as the intersection of the 2nd and 3rd segment, but not the 3rd and 1st segment.

Comment: @vercassivelaunos you are right i chose bad  words i meant the union of the two to be connected. And you are right. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
\begin{align*}
        f_{1}(z)&=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}\quad r>0,0<\theta<\pi\\
        f_{2}(z)&=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}\quad r<0,\pi/2<\theta<2\pi\\
        f_{3}(z)&=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}\quad r<0,3\pi/2<\theta<5\pi/2\\ 
\end{align*}

All three functions are analytic in their domains, $f_ {1} = f_ {2}$ at the intersection of their domains $ \frac{\pi}{2} <\theta <\pi $. So $ f_ {2}$ is an analytic extension of $ f_ {1}$.

Similarly, $ f_ {2} = f_ {3} $ in $ \frac{3\pi}{2} <\theta <2 \pi $, so $ f_ {3} $ is an analytic extension of $ f_ {2} $, however $ f_ {3} (z) = -f_ {1} (z) $, for any $ z $ in the first quadrant,

for example:

$z = 1 + i $, $ f_ {3} (1 + i ) = f_ {2} (\sqrt {2} e^{i (\frac{\pi}{4} + 2 \pi}) = - 2 ^ {1/4} e^{i \frac{\pi}{8}} $, but $ f_ {1} (1 + i) = f (\sqrt {2} e^ {i\frac{\pi}{4}}) = 2 ^ {1/4} e ^ {\frac{\pi}{8}} $, therefore $ f_ {3} $ is not an analytic extension of $ f_ {2} $.

Comment: thanks for your help. What's the point of negative r in the first segment? I guess it doesn't contribute to any changes. and isn't it true that we use r and $\theta$ where r is a positive real number in polar coordinate?

Comment: @eksplor you're welcome, yes $r>0$